# android - how to run task if recycle view only if scrolls down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a recycle view ,I want to run asynTask when user reached the end of recycleview . this is my code :

```
recycle.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = recycle.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loadmore) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loadmore = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                }
            }
            if (!loadmore && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                    <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                if(taskrunning!=null && taskrunning==false){
                    loadmore = false;
                    page = page + 1;
                    new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

it works find when I reach the end of recycleView but when I scrollup , it calls the asynctask again .

I don't want to call asyncTask when I scrollup , I want to call it only when I scroll down .

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Set `loadmore` to true at the location I pointed below.

```
recycle.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = recycle.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loadmore) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loadmore = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loadmore && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            if(taskrunning!=null && taskrunning==false){
                loadmore = true; // SET TO TRUE HERE!
                page = page + 1;
                new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And set `loadmore = false` in the `onPostExecute` part of your `AsyncTask`.